# How can I add my products to my home page?

Tags: magento-1.8, home

I've insert 5 products and I wanted them to appear on my home page. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to assign them to a category and add the following to the content section of your CMS homepage replacing the part with `[ ]` with the actual category ID

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home_list" category_id="[the category id]"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: No problem, if it works make sure to accept the answer to close the question!

Comment: Need to wait 5sec xD